# Only filter Array for the defined parameters. ignore empty parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an array of projects, which can be filtered by three select dropdowns. once the user selects an option the option will be passed in the components state through the store. i just dont know how to handle the cases where one of the filter options is empty and an empty filter option is passed. also i would like to have the option to show all and ignore the filter. I just get the or logic to work like to be able to only filter for years and if i filter places or types the years already set getting ignored but i would also like to filter all three.

```
export class Projects extends React.Component {



constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
    this.state = {
      initialItems: props.data.projects.edges,
      items: null,
      filterPlace: '',
      filterYear: '',
      filterType: '',
    };
    this.placesOptions = new Set();
    this.yearsOptions = new Set();
    this.typesOptions =  new Set();
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    const { initialItems } = this.state
    this.setState({items: initialItems})

    initialItems.map((item) => {
      this.placesOptions.add(item.node.categories_names[0].name)
      this.yearsOptions.add(item.node.categories_names[1].name)
      this.typesOptions.add(item.node.categories_names[2].name)
    })
  }

  // TODO: FIX BUG ON RELOAD ALL EMPTY
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps !== this.props) {
      this.filterProjects()
    }
  }

  filterProjects(){
    const { filterPlace, filterYear, filterType } = this.props;
    let updatedList = this.state.initialItems;
    updatedList = updatedList.filter((item) => {
      const itemFilterCategory = item.node.categories_names
      const placeQueryString = itemFilterCategory[0].name.toString().toLowerCase()
      const yearQueryString = itemFilterCategory[1].name.toString().toLowerCase()
      const typeQueryString = itemFilterCategory[2].name.toString().toLowerCase()
      return (
        filterPlace !== "" && placeQueryString.search( filterPlace.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
        filterYear !== "" && yearQueryString.search( filterYear.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
        filterType !== "" && typeQueryString.search( filterType.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      )
    });
    this.setState({items: updatedList});
  }

  render() {
    const { location, data } = this.props;
    const { items } = this.state;
    const { page } = data;
    return (
      <MainLayout location={location}>
        <TopNavigation />
        <Header
          siteBrand={config.siteBrand}
          siteSubtitle={page.title}
          isProjectArchive
        />
        <ConnectedProjectFilter
          changeHandlerSearch={(e) => this.searchProjects(e)}
          placesOptions={this.placesOptions}
          yearsOptions={this.yearsOptions}
          typesOptions={this.typesOptions}
        />
        <ProjectArchiveListing projects={items} />
      </MainLayout>
    )
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  filterPlace: state.filterPlace,
  filterYear: state.filterYear,
  filterType: state.filterType,
});


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Projects)
```

Comment: Why not just use an `if()` statement to check if the input is empty?

Comment: hey @JossClassey i already thought about that, but than i would have to use multiple if statements to check the different combinations and the code gets a mess. like if filterPlace return ... if filterPlace && filterYear return ... if filterPlace && filterYear && filterType return ... you get the point haha. i just think there has to be a smarter way.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about what you're trying to achieve. Do you want the code to run if any of the props are empty?

Comment: @JossClassey no. i just want it to run when at least one of the props has a value. so basically a multi filter. which can filter for one but also several properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want any empty input to match (pass through) every item then I believe this is the condition you want:

```
(filterPlace === "" || placeQueryString.search( filterPlace.toLowerCase()) !== -1) &&
 (filterYear === "" || yearQueryString.search( filterYear.toLowerCase()) !== -1) &&
 (filterType === "" || typeQueryString.search( filterType.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
```

To describe it in words, you want each passing item to be valid with respect to every filter. To validate with a filter the filter must allow all (be empty) or the item must match the filter.

Comment: thank you so much. it is working :). and thanks for the description it helped me understanding the problem. i a new here. so unfortunately i cant upvote your answer.